# cythonize not found on Ubuntu 22.04 after "pip3 install cython"

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, cython, cythonize

```
Command: cythonize rednose/helpers/ekf_sym_pyx.pyx
Error: sh: 1: cythonize: not found
```

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04. I was trying to install `https://github.com/commaai/rednose`.

Few days back, while working on Ubuntu 18.04, I got the same issue, I solved it by using `pip3 install cython`.

On Ubuntu 22.04, it's not solving the same way. What's the proper way to install the `cythonize` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Jammy repositories of 22.04, cython has been named cython3. So install it with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install cython3`

Comment: attention, this is version 0.29